# Devise - Unexpected 'Your Username or Password is invalid' message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have an interesting problem. Whenever I am trying to go to the unauthorized resource, devise successfully redirects me to signs up page but... unexpectedly throws "Your Username or Password is invalid." error message.  What can possible go, wrong? Any hints would be appreciated.

Many Thanks.

**EDIT**
The user model is quite stock standard:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable 

  devise :registerable
  devise :omniauthable

  # boring stuff ommitted
end
```

Comment: maybe you need to confirm the account

Comment: please paste your user model code.

Comment: the user model is stock-standard in terms of devise, it just register the model it uses.

Comment: Why do you have registerable twice?

Comment: Nothing declared as attr_accessible / attr_accessor ?

Comment: @simonmorley, good spot, thanks!  I've removed the double occurrence of registerable, but still the same behavior.

Comment: @citraL Yep I have some stuff if attr_accessible / attr_accessor.  Can this be relevant?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you had left `attr_accessor :password` while using Devise, which would prevent Devise from encrypting your password, and generate an "Invalid Username/Password" message, even if valid data are entered in the sign-in fields.